# Button on ToolBar won't open the Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, android-navigationview

I have created a Base Activity that contains a navigation drawer.

The drawer will open on slide, but never through the navigation button on the toolbar. I've been stuck on this for quite a while, and I had it working prior to creating this base class and I don't think I've changed anything logically.

I know this question has been asked before, but I've gone through all other similar posts and have not been able to solve it.

Thanks in advance!

```
public class DrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


protected DrawerLayout          drawerLayout;
private   ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
private   Toolbar               toolbar;
private   NavigationView        navigationView;
private   boolean               enableToolbar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    enableToolbar  =  true;

}


@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID){
    super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);
    setToolbar();
    setDrawerLayout();
    setNavigationDrawer();
    setToolbarOnClickListener();
    if(!useToolbar())
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    inflateToContentFrame(layoutResID);
}


public void setUsesToolbar(boolean _enable){
    enableToolbar = _enable;
}


private boolean useToolbar(){
    return enableToolbar;
}


private void setToolbar(){
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}


private void setDrawerLayout(){
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_drawer, null);
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close){

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            DrawerActivity.this.invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            DrawerActivity.this.invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            DrawerActivity.this.toolbar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset / 2);
        }
    };

    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    drawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            toggle.syncState();
        }
    });

}

private void setNavigationDrawer(){
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}


private void setToolbarOnClickListener(){
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DrawerActivity.this.drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });
}


private void inflateToContentFrame(int layoutResID){
    FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, content, true);
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.drawer, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    Intent _intent;
    if (id == R.id.nav_classes) {
        _intent = new Intent(this, AppointmentsActivity.class);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_appointments) {
        _intent = new Intent(this, AppointmentsActivity.class);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_clients) {
        _intent = new Intent(this, AppointmentsActivity.class);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_payments) {
        _intent = new Intent(this, AppointmentsActivity.class);
    } else if(id == R.id.nav_Settings){
        _intent = new Intent(this, AppointmentsActivity.class);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        _intent = new Intent(this, AppointmentsActivity.class);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
        _intent = new Intent(this, AppointmentsActivity.class);
    }else{
        _intent = new Intent(this, AppointmentsActivity.class);
    }

    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    startActivity(_intent);
    return true;
}



}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>


<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />



<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_drawer"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_drawer_drawer"
    />




</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DrawerLayout` instance you're setting up the Toggle with is not the instance that's on-screen. In the `setDrawerLayout()` method, you're inflating a new layout that's never used.

Instead of inflating there, use `findViewById()` to get the `DrawerLayout` instance that's created and added to the `Activity` in the `super.setContentView()` call.

```
drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

Also, you can omit the `toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener()` call, as the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` will set a listener itself, and handle opening and closing the drawer internally.